# Overflow: Hidden doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to use the Masonry jQuery package to make an image gallery and want to have an effect where the picture you hover over enlarges. I've gotten all of this to work, but my problem lies in the fact that I can't get the `overflow:hidden` to work. My images just expand past where I'd like them to get cut off.

Any useful tips would be welcome. Here's some of my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 test2"></div>

    <div class="col-md-10 test2">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="grow pic_float_w1h2"><img class="grid-item grid-item--height2" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/people/9"></div>
            <div><img class="grid-item grid-item--height2 grid-item--width3" src="http://www.placehold.it/800x800"></div>
            <div><img class="grid-item grid-item--width3 grid-item--height2" src="http://www.placehold.it/800x800"></div>
            <div><img class="grid-item" src="http://www.placehold.it/800x800"></div>
            <div class="grow pic_float_w1h2"><img class="grid-item grid-item--height2" src="https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/VM43QLTKXE.jpg"></div>
            <div><img class="grid-item grid-item--height" src="http://www.placehold.it/800x800"></div>
            <div><img class="grid-item grid-item--height2 grid-item--width4" src="http://www.placehold.it/800x800"></div>
            <div><img class="grid-item grid-item--height3" src="http://www.placehold.it/800x800"></div>
            <div><img class="grid-item grid-item--height1 grid-item--width2" src="http://www.placehold.it/800x800"></div>
            <div><img class="grid-item" src="http://www.placehold.it/800x800"></div>
            <div><img class="grid-item grid-item--width2" src="http://www.placehold.it/800x800"></div>
            <div><img class="grid-item" src="http://www.placehold.it/800x800"></div>
            <div><img class="grid-item grid-item--width2" src="http://www.placehold.it/800x800"></div>
            <div><img class="grid-item grid-item--width4" src="http://www.placehold.it/800x800"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container_gallery {
  margin-top: 5%;
}


/* ---- Gallery ---- */
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

/* ---- grid ---- */

.grid {
  max-width: 1200px;
  max-height: 800px;
}

/* clearfix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- grid-item ---- */

.grid-item {
  width: 160px;
  height: 120px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
  border-radius: 0px;
}

/*
.grid-item:hover {
  opacity: 0.3; filter: alpha(opacity=30);
}
*/

.grid-item--width2 { width: 320px; }
.grid-item--width3 { width: 480px; }
.grid-item--width4 { width: 640px; }

.grid-item--height2 { height: 200px; }
.grid-item--height3 { height: 260px; }
.grid-item--height4 { height: 360px; }

 /* ---- Gallery End ---- */

.grow .pic_float_w1h2 img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 160px;

  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
}

.grow img:hover {
  height: 300px;
  width: 260px;
}
```

Comment: Where's the CSS with `overflow` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for somethings like this

```
  .grow img:hover {
     height: 300px;
     width: 260px;
     max-height: 300px;
     max-width: 260px; 
   }
```

Comment: I tried doing that, but it still doesn't work. Could this be interfering with some of the jQuery plugins/libs the site is using?

Comment: Try settimh max width and height. have update the answer